# jQuery Animate Easing on specific property

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, easing

I want to animate 4 properties:

top, width, opacity and height

Now i have them all set to default easing and duration of 500.

I want to set the opacity easing to easeInQuad using an easing plugin. If i set the animate easing then all the properties use that easing method. If i animate the opacity in its own animate method, it will only animate after the first animate finishes. Is there anyway i can use this easing method for opacity while the other properties use the default and have them both happen at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read http://api.jquery.com/animate#per-property-easing ?

Comment: @mblase75 - write that as an answer and I'll vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read http://api.jquery.com/animate#per-property-easing for details.